# How to output mininet-wifi cli commands to a text file

Tags: python, mininet

I am trying to take rssi output from mininet cli and I am running  py sta1.params['rssi'] in a script (since I have multiple stations). I could see the output in cli but when I try to output in a text file, it gives me output as `<mininet.net.Mininet object at 0x7f384d80f910>`.

I tried looking into and found that it is referencing the object. I checked cli.py from mininet to understand from where output is coming, but I didnt get any luck.

I can use iwconfig and parse the part I want, but I still need distance between stations.

I would like to get help in trying to output CLI commands into a text file.

Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify the sentence "I could see the output in cli but when I try to output in a text file, it gives me output as <mininet.net.Mininet object at 0x7f384d80f910>"?

Comment: So when I run the command the output is displayed in the terminal, but if I want to print to text file I couldn’t get it

Comment: Which command? How are you using such command? and where?

Comment: so I am trying to data = CLI(net, my_script)
print data.

my_script has py sta1.params['rssi']

Comment: Why don't you use "print sta1.params['rssi']", directly?

Comment: I could print in the mininet-wifi, but I would like to get it inside a text file, so I could make use of the data.

Comment: So, you have many possibilities. Why don't you use cat? cat var >> text.txt.

Comment: Ramon, I tried it a bit different, but I am getting output. However, the commands are still need to be written inside the the topology code which I am writing. If I run as a shell command, I still get the same message. However, this works for me, thanks a lot for the help. Really appreciate it .